# Accesing laravel public folder using root index file

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel Version - 5.8.

I have to deploy my Laravel project on Shared Hosting without using `php artisan serve` command. So for that reason, I have renamed my root file *server.php* file to *index.php*.

Will there be any security consequences or bug, if I rename the file *server.php* to *index.php*?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to rename server.php to index.php. Just move the Public/index.php to the root of the folder and change the necessary path inside the index.php after moving. It will work for sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you using cPanel, you can change webroot to `public` very simple don't need to rename `server.php`. If not you can using `.htaccess` to redirect all request to `public` folder like this :

```
# public_html/.htaccess

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect All Requests To The Subfolder
    RewriteRule ^ /public

</IfModule>
```